# Count number of male and female in a given range

Tags: excel

I have a workbook with about 3000 table rows of student data categorized according to their name, gender (male or female), age and age range (<=13, 14-17 and 18-20). I want to extract the total number of number of male and female that fall within each age range. I've tried using using `Countifs()` function, but it doesn't seem to recognise the <13 range. How can I achieve this by any means for the purpose of constructing a pivot-chart.
Please, see the workbook at https://1drv.ms/x/s!AghFlVg6p0YpkCRqvKvd4_5gOsNq?e=QPoMWD

Comment: most will not download a workbook from a public site.  Also the question should stand on its own and not rely on a link that may be lost in the future.  Please [edit] the post and include a [mcve] with either pictures or tabular data that expresses the problem

Comment: but,  to use contifs with the `<=13` use `"="&"<=13"` you need to put the `=` in front to let COUNTIFS know you are looking for the literal string.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right about using "="&"=<13", it worked. I only had to divide the `Countifs()` result by the total number if subject. For the uploaded workbook, my bad!